# Python [:-1] vs remove

Tags: python, list, function, reference, instance-variables

While writing a recursive function in python, I noticed an interesting phenomenon. `.append` will change an input variable, but `=` creates a private instance variable in the function. For example, using equals does not affect `a,`

```
>>> def f(x):
        x=x[:-1]
>>> a=[1, 2, 3]
>>> f(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

while using append changes `a.`

```
>>> def g(x):
        x.remove(3)

>>> g(a)
>>> a
[1, 2]
>>>
```

I assume this is because `.remove` edits the reference, while `[:-1]` creates a new list, but is there a reason why this occurs?

Comment: run it on [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/) and you will see how references work - see blue arrows in visualisations.

Comment: Ned explains everything your need to know [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) perfectly.

Comment: Already have answer `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Ned Batchelder - Facts and Myths about Python names and values - PyCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns):

Functions like `x.append("something")` and `x.remove("something")` **mutate** a value, and change their values. However, using `x=x+["something"]` or `x=x[:-1]` **rebind** a reference, and create a new value which the variable now points to.

Thanks to [@timgeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3620003/timgeb) for commenting the video!

Comment: Note: A mutating slice assignment could be used to make it work (it would just be less efficient, since it would involve making a potentially huge temporary `list` just to remove one item), via `x[:] = x[:-1]`, because that's reassigning the range of values, not rebinding `x`.

Answer (score 0):

In this code: `.append` is a function of **x**, so the **x** is the same instance; but, `x = [1]`, the **x** will create a new instance. Try this:

```
def f(x):
    print(x, id(x))
    x = [1]
    print(x, id(x))
```